# Getting "connection refused" when trying to access etcd from within a Docker container

Tags: networking, docker, etcd

I am trying to access etcd from within a running Docker container. When I run

```
curl http://172.17.42.1:4001/v2/keys
```

I get

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.42.1 port 4001: Connection refused
```

I have four other hosts where this works fine, but every container on this machine has this problem. I'm really at a loss as to what's going on, and I don't know how to debug it.

My etcd environment variables are

```
ETCD_ADVERTISE_CLIENT_URLS=http://10.242.10.2:2379
ETCD_DISCOVERY=https://discovery.etcd.io/<token_removed>
ETCD_INITIAL_ADVERTISE_PEER_URLS=http://10.242.10.2:2380
ETCD_LISTEN_CLIENT_URLS=http://10.242.10.2:2379,http://127.0.0.1:2379,http://0.0.0.0:4001
ETCD_LISTEN_PEER_URLS=http://10.242.10.2:2380
```

I can also access etcd from the host with

```
curl http://localhost:4001/v2/keys
```

So there seems to be some error when routing from the container out to the host. But I can't figure out what it is. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you sure etcd is listening on that IP? `172.17.42.1` looks like the docker0 ip. Use `ss -l ` to list open server sockets. I guess etcd is listening on a different IP.

Comment: Hmm you're right. Etcd is only listening on `127.0.0.1:4001`, even though I have `0.0.0.0:4001` in my config. I'm not sure why it's not respecting that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out etcd was only listening on `localhost:4001` on that machine, which is why I couldn't access it from within a container. This is despite me configuring one of the listen client urls to `0.0.0.0:4001`.

It turns out that I had run `sudo systemctl enable etcd2`, which caused it to run before the cloud-config service ran. As such, etcd started with default configuration instead of the one that I had specified in my cloud config. Running `sudo systemctl disable etcd2` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 7):

I observed I had to use the --advertise-client-urls and --listen-client-urls.  Like so:

```
./etcd --advertise-client-urls 'http://0.0.0.0:2379,http://0.0.0.0:4001' --listen-client-urls 'http://0.0.0.0:2379,http://0.0.0.0:4001'
```

Then I was able to successfully do

```
curl -L http://hostname:2379/version
```

from any machine that could reach that server and it worked.

Comment: Can't upvote this enough. Wish this was pointed out as required for running etcd in docker. Thanks.